# I need to mock CosmosClient for writing unit test using xunit and moq

Tags: cosmosclient

I am using GetItemLinqQueryable().where(predicate).TofeedIterator().readnextasync() to retrieve item from db. how can i mock these cosmosclient method so that i can run unit testing?